# Calculate decision boundaries and class probabilities based on data

Tags: classification, python

I have a dataset with one independent variable and a corresponding label. For example, let's assume we have the amount of hours studied for a test as our x variable and the grade of the test afterwards with 0 = "Bad", 1 = "Medium" and 2 = "Good" as the y variable.

Made up example data and code in Python:

```
x = [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 30, 35]
y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
plt.scatter(x,y, marker = 'o')
```

When plotting this data the graph is shaped like a step funcion but the boundaries between the classes flow into each other.

1. What methods can I use to statistically calculate the decision boundaries between the three classes based on the available data?
2. How can I get the probability for each of the grades given the amount of studied hours (e.g. 7 hours -> 70% Good, 30% Medium, 0% Bad)?

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated, and thank you for asking a good question with sample data!

Answer (score 1):

Your outcomes are ordinally scaled. The standard tool is [ordinal (logistic) regression](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=ordinal+logistic+regression). Googling will find you lots of resources to do this in Python, e.g., [in statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/ordinal_regression.html).